# Is there any kind of distributive law for $c\cdot\max(a,b)$, allowing both signs of $c$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality, maxima-minima, lattice-orders, conjunctive-normal-form

Notation: For any two numbers $a$ and $b$, let the maximum be $a\sqcap b$, and let the minimum be $a\sqcup b$. (No, my symbols aren't [upside-down](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797634/origins-of-conjunction-and-disjunction-symbols-wedge-and-vee-in-formal-l). Compare this with floor notation; $\lfloor a\rfloor\leq a$, and likewise $a\sqcup b\leq a$.)

Addition distributes over max and min, and max and min distribute over each other:

$$ c + (a \sqcap b) = (c + a) \sqcap (c + b) \qquad -(a \sqcap b) = (-a) \sqcup (-b) $$
$$ c + (a \sqcup b) = (c + a) \sqcup (c + b) \qquad -(a \sqcup b) = (-a) \sqcap (-b) $$
$$ c \sqcap (a \sqcup b) = (c \sqcap a) \sqcup (c \sqcap b) \qquad c \sqcup (a \sqcap b) = (c \sqcup a) \sqcap (c \sqcup b) $$

It follows that any expression involving these operations can be put in a form where the "$+$" and "$-$" signs are innermost, and only "$\sqcap$" and "$\sqcup$" apply to parentheses. So, to reduce the number of parentheses, let's extend the standard order of operations: Multiplication and division are done first (left to right), then addition and subtraction (left to right), then maximum and minimum (left to right).

$$ (a + b) \sqcap (c + d) = a + b \sqcap c + d \neq a + (b \sqcap c) + d $$
$$ (a \cdot b) \sqcap (c \cdot d) = a \cdot b \sqcap c \cdot d \neq a \cdot (b \sqcap c) \cdot d $$

However, multiplication doesn't properly distribute:

$$ c\cdot(a \sqcap b) = \begin{cases} c\cdot a \sqcap c\cdot b, \quad c\geq0 \\ c\cdot a \sqcup c\cdot b, \quad c\leq0 \end{cases} $$

**Question:** Is $c\cdot(a \sqcap b)$ represented by an expression involving the symbols "$a,b,c,+,-,\cdot,\sqcap,\sqcup,(,),0,1$" (and maybe other real constants), where "$+$" and "$-$" and "$\cdot$" are never adjacent to "$($" or "$)$"?

(Don't cheat and try something like "$c\cdot1(a \sqcap b)$", which should be "$c\cdot1\cdot(a \sqcap b)$".)

Equivalently, are there polynomials $p_{i,j}$ in three variables such that

$$ \begin{align} c\cdot(a \sqcap b) & = \big(p_{1,1}(a,b,c) \sqcap p_{1,2}(a,b,c) \sqcap p_{1,3}(a,b,c) \sqcap \cdots\big) \\ &\; \sqcup \big(p_{2,1}(a,b,c) \sqcap p_{2,2}(a,b,c) \sqcap p_{2,3}(a,b,c) \sqcap \cdots\big) \\ &\; \sqcup \big(p_{3,1}(a,b,c) \sqcap p_{3,2}(a,b,c) \sqcap p_{3,3}(a,b,c) \sqcap \cdots\big) \\ &\; \sqcup \;\vdots \end{align} $$

for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ ?

(I think it would follow that any expression, not just $c\cdot(a \sqcap b)$, can be put in the same form, by repeatedly applying these distributive laws. But I'm not really sure. The process might never end, always making the expression more complicated.)

---

We can decompose any number as the difference of two non-negative numbers:

$$ c = (0 \sqcap c) + (0 \sqcup c) = (0 \sqcap c) - (0 \sqcap -c) $$

Thus, since positive numbers distribute over max and min, we have

$$ c\cdot(a \sqcap b) = (0 \sqcap c)\cdot(a \sqcap b) - (0 \sqcap -c)\cdot(a \sqcap b) $$
$$ = ((0 \sqcap c)\cdot a \sqcap (0 \sqcap c)\cdot b) - ((0 \sqcap -c)\cdot a \sqcap (0 \sqcap -c)\cdot b) $$
$$ = (a\cdot(0 \sqcap c) \sqcap b\cdot(0 \sqcap c)) - (a\cdot(0 \sqcap -c) \sqcap b\cdot(0 \sqcap -c)) $$

This shows that it suffices to find a formula for $a\cdot(0 \sqcap c)$, or equivalently $a\cdot(0 \sqcap b)$; the number of variables is reduced from three to two. In fact there's another way to show this:

$$ a \sqcap b = (a-b \sqcap 0) + b $$
$$ c\cdot(a \sqcap b) = c\cdot(0 \sqcap a-b) + c\cdot b $$

If that term $c\cdot(0 \sqcap a-b)$ can be expressed in the desired form, then (since addition distributes) we can simply add $c\cdot b$ to all the polynomials $p_{i,j}$.

Furthermore, this is also equivalent to finding a formula for $(0 \sqcap a)\cdot(0 \sqcap b)$:

$$ a\cdot(0 \sqcap b) = (0 \sqcap a)\cdot(0 \sqcap b) - (0 \sqcap -a)\cdot(0 \sqcap b) $$

---

Related: [Are there any theories being developed which study structures with many operations and many distributive laws?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120611/are-there-any-theories-being-developed-which-study-structures-with-many-operatio)

I couldn't find good tags for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But the expressions I found are somewhat complicated and asymmetric. If anyone can find anything nicer, please post another answer.

$$ (0 \sqcap a)\cdot(0 \sqcap b) = \begin{cases} a\cdot b, \quad a\geq0 \;\text{and}\; b\geq0 \\ \;\;0,\;\; \quad a\leq0 \;\;\text{or}\;\; b\leq0 \end{cases} $$
$$ = (0 \sqcap a\cdot b) \sqcup (0 \sqcap a \sqcap a\cdot b\cdot b) $$

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive. Then $ab\leq a$ when $b\leq1$, and $ab\leq ab^2$ when $b\geq1$, so in either case $ab\leq a \sqcap ab^2$. This is the basis of most of these formulas.

$$ a\cdot(0 \sqcap b) = \begin{cases} a\cdot b, \quad b\geq0 \\ \;\;0,\;\; \quad b\leq0 \end{cases} $$
$$ = \big(ab \sqcup (0 \sqcap a \sqcap ab^2)\big) \sqcap (0 \sqcup a \sqcup ab^2) $$
$$ = \big(ab \sqcap (0 \sqcup a \sqcup ab^2)\big) \sqcup (0 \sqcap a \sqcap ab^2) $$
$$ = \big(ab \sqcup (0 \sqcap b \sqcap a^2b)\big) \sqcap (0 \sqcup -b \sqcup -a^2b) $$
$$ = \big(ab \sqcap (0 \sqcup -b \sqcup -a^2b)\big) \sqcup (0 \sqcap b \sqcap a^2b) $$
$$ = (0 \sqcap ab) \sqcup (ab \sqcap a) \sqcup (ab \sqcap ab^2) \sqcup (0 \sqcap a \sqcap ab^2) $$

Replacing $a$ with $c$ and $b$ with $a-b$:

$$ c\cdot(0 \sqcap a-b) $$
$$ = \big(0 \sqcap c(a-b)\big) \sqcup \big(c(a-b) \sqcap c\big) \sqcup \big(c(a-b) \sqcap c(a-b)^2\big) \sqcup \big(0 \sqcap c \sqcap c(a-b)^2\big) $$

Adding $c\cdot b$:

$$ c\cdot(a \sqcap b) $$
$$ = \big(cb \sqcap ca\big) \sqcup \big(ca \sqcap c+cb\big) \sqcup \big(ca \sqcap c(a-b)^2+cb\big) \sqcup \big(cb \sqcap c+cb \sqcap c(a-b)^2+cb\big) $$